Can the impedance of the source affect the response of a high-pass filter?
Having a simple RC high-pass filter, can a high signal impedance change the cutoff frequency response? Or more practically, should a resistor before the capacitor be included in the calculation for fcut? If so, would a volume potentiometer before the filter also affect the fcut.


can a high signal impedance change the cutoff frequency response?

Yes.

should a resistor before the capacitor be included in the calculation for fcut?

Yes.

If so, would a volume potentiometer before the filter also affect the fcut.

Yes.
Although the phrase "signal impedance" is often used, it actually means the source impedance.
To calculate the resistance seen by the capacitor, a good circuit diagram is required.
Figure 1 shows a circuit that represents what is described. R1 is the impedance of the source V1. R2 is a the volume control. R3 is the load on the high pass filter.
To determine the cut-off frequency, the time constant τ is required. The resistance seen by the capacitance is the Thevenin resistance RTh. Figure two shows the circuit modified to find RTh.
As can be seen, in addition to the filter resistor, the volume control and the source resistance are both included in the series path connecting the two terminals of the capacitor.
The volume control will vary the cutoff as the volume is adjusted, so perhaps would be better placed after the filter as shown in Figure 3.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

thank you very much

Cheers @boromyr


Can the impedance of the source affect the response of a high-pass filter?

Yes.
Here is a circuit with a source impedance and a high pass filter.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Here is the frequency response with values of Rsource being 0.1, 1, 10 and 100 ohms. The input voltage is taken after Rsource. The node marked Vinput is not a separate input signal but is needed for calculating the frequency response.

Clearly the source impedance is affecting the frequency response.

thank you very much
